# Syntax error when creating a function

Tags: python

I am rather new to python and working through it. I am trying to create a function that will create a time message. The word "year" in my code comes back highlighted and showing it is invalid syntax. The code is incomplete at the moment and a few things I need to fix, I am just kind of lost at the moment.

**the problem I am trying to solve is:**

create function timeMessage

Arguments: None

Body: Import asctime function from time module
Create newtimeline using day of week, space, month, space, day, space, year, space time from asctime function
Return newtimeline

**my code:**

```
def timeMessage():

    from time import asctime
    from time import localtime
    asctime
    localtime
    myTime = timestring
    myTime = myTime.split(" ")
    newTimeline = week + " " + month + " " + day + " " year + " " + localtime
    return newTimeline
```

Comment: You're missing a `+` before the `year`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `+` showing that you are including the `year` variable after the `" "`.

Like this:

```
def timeMessage():

    from time import asctime
    from time import localtime
    asctime
    localtime
    myTime = timestring
    myTime = myTime.split(" ")
    newTimeline = week + " " + month + " " + day + " " + year + " " + localtime
    return newTimeline
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, thank you.